# What is the correct maximum value for resistor R₁?

Tags: led, diodes, cmos, ttl

How do I calculate the maximum value of resistor R<sub>1</sub> if the following values are known:

- V<sub>DD</sub> = 5 V
- inverter CMOS CD4069UB
- I<sub>IL</sub> = I<sub>IH</sub> = 0 mA
- V<sub>OH</sub> = 4.95 V
- V<sub>OL</sub> = 0.5 V
- I<sub>OH</sub> = I<sub>OL</sub> = 0.6 mA
- V<sub>D</sub> = 1 V
- maximum allowed dissipation on resistor R<sub>1</sub> is P<sub>d</sub> = 0.125 W

[image: problem schema]

I've calculate the minimum value of resistor R<sub>1</sub> when the SW is ON using the dissipation:

$$R_{1(min)}=\frac{V_{DD}^2}{P_d}=200\,\Omega$$

I've also tried to calculate the maximum value of resistor R<sub>1</sub> when the SW is OFF:

$$R_{1(max)}=\frac{V_{IL}}{I_{IL}}$$

The problem here is that I don't have a value for V<sub>IL</sub> and the value for I<sub>IL</sub> = 0 mA.

Are my calculations correct? If not, how do I calculate the max. value of R<sub>1</sub>? Is it possible for CMOS to have I<sub>IL</sub> = 0 mA?

Comment: At least [TI tells that](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/cd4069ub) V_IL is max. 1 V @ 5V supply, and I_IN (no matter if I_IL or I_IH) is worst case 1 µA. AndyAka's answer is a good practical advice, and it depends a bit on how much current do you want to waste when the switch is closed. Basically from few tens of ohms to what you compute from V_IL and so on ( some 100 k&ohm;) is "correct".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. While AndyAka's answer is a good practical advice it doesn't help me solve this particular problem which might not be very applicable to the real world. If I understand you correctly, the problems specification that the \$I_{IL}=0\,mA\$ is incorrect because the \$I_{IN}\$ is at least 1 µA?

Comment: Well do you want an ideal answer based on your data or practical answer?

Comment: @Justme I would like an answer based on the given data.

Comment: @AleksaMajkic That's what I was afraid of, because it's unrealistic. With the data you give, like you already calculated, no current through any resistance equals no voltage drop. Therefore any resistance up to infinity is an answer, as long as there is a resistance so it is not completely removed from circuit. Which is not what you can do in practice. So either the data is invalid or any arbitratily high resistance will do. Unless you add the leakage current to the data, and limits for valid input voltages.

Comment: @Justme this is more or less the answer I was looking for. Thank you. I had my doubts about the the validity of the data given to me with this problem but I wasn't entirely certain. I agree, the answer is any resistance up to infinity when using the provided data even though it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @AleksaMajkic The given data are wrong. I_IL / I_IH is specified in the datasheet, and the datasheet is known as the part number is given.  In practice it may be much lower than this (~nA is normal, ~pA might not even be unusual), but you can't plan for "typical" here, it should work under the worst-case expected conditions.

Comment: The CMOS gate input current I_IL is the maximum current to expect under worst conditions. Since you must make sure the input-low voltage stays below V_IL (1.0 V in this case) it means that a pull-down resistor of 1 MOhm or less counters this aspect. You also have a non-ideal switch. To counter what the switch does AndyAka's hints are to be considered. Because in your case and in a real setup the switch might be the trouble-maker, the maximum of 500 k is set (this can mitigate both influences).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After gaining access to this problem's solution I learned what was a correct answer. The expected answer was
$$R_{1(max)} \to\infty.$$
I personally don't agree completely with this answer. If you don't take this answer at face value, than you must take a look at the infinity and its meaning. Infinity isn't a number that can measure a quantity of something, e.q. resistance. You could wonder what does the resistance approach as the current becomes arbitrarily small, in which case you would have:
$$ \lim_{I_{IL}\to 0} \frac{V_{IL}}{I_{IL}} = \infty\,\text{.}$$
Unfortunately the problem wasn't worded as such as it claims that I<sub>IL</sub> = 0 mA. It is important to note that I<sub>IL</sub> → 0 mA isn't the same as saying the current is zero. Resistance R<sub>1</sub> can't be increased all the way to infinity, so we can't ever decrease current to zero.
Because I<sub>IL</sub>=0 mA, we are dividing by zero, which is a good hint we are approaching something that can't happen.

Comment: Infinitely high resistance is an answer, at least mathematically - if no current flows through it, any resistance, as high or even higher you can imagine will suffice, as long as the resistance is there. If you remove the resistance, the problem becomes undefined. In a real chip the leakage current is said to be +/- 1 microamps.

Comment: FWIW I agree it's bad form to ask a question on a test, but not provide enough information for a sensible answer.

Answer (score 4):

With the data given, there is no sensible answer as you have already calculated.

With no input current, any resistance, even infinitely high, will have no voltage drop.

A more practical data for the chip includes leakage current, and some range of valid voltages, and for example 1 μA and 1 V would give 1 MΩ.

Answer (score 3):

> *What is the correct maximum value for the resistor R1?*

Pretty much this is determined by the minimum reliable operating current for the switch. The minimum current might be e.g. 10 μA so, you'd use a resistor value that is lower than 5 volts ÷ 10 μA = 500 kΩ.

If the switch data sheet doesn't specify a minimum operating current, I'd look for one that did.

It has nothing to do with the CMOS gate in 99.999 % of cases unless the switch specified a min current in the nano amp region (I've never see that).

Comment: This conversation is not going in a good direction, I have purged the comments

Comment: Note that "wiping current" can be afforded with a bypass capacitor; it should have some ESR to also limit peak current, avoiding contact wear. The capacitor can further be sized to afford debounce filtering, if that should prove useful.

Comment: Do you mean [wetting current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wetting_current) @TimWilliams

Comment: Oh yes, "wiping" is the mechanical equivalent, heh.

Answer (score 1):

You can't calculate it from the information given.

There are a number of factors that make it unwise to make your pullup too high but how high is too high depends on factors not discussed in your problem.

1. What is the minimum current for the switch to operate reliablly? switches can be problematic at very low currents.
2. What is the capacitance of the system, and how fast does the state need to change.
3. What external influences is the system subject to.

I have a board here with a 74LVC device as an input buffers, I have jumpers on the board to select pull-up, pull-down or no pull at all. If I have nothing connected to the input and no pull-up/pull-down jumper in place then just waving my hand around in the vicinity of the board will make the inputs change state.